# duplication of same citation in a slide with \footcite{} in Beamer

Tags: latex, citations, footnotes

I am using class beamer to prepare scientific presentation. The myrefernces.bib is included using \addbibresource{}. In one slide, one citation is used twice using \footcite{}. The same citation appears twice in the bottom of the slide also with different numbers. How to avoid this and make the citation appear with same number in the slide as well as through out presentation to avoid confusion.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you tried the citeonce(page) option to the package? It should solve your problem.

Comment: If you crosspost on different sites, the least you should do is to include links to the other posts

Comment: Thanks.. it seems citeonce(page) option is not available with biblatex.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

manual workaround:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage[style=authoryear]{biblatex} 
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@book{knuth,
  author       = {Knuth, Donald E.},
  title        = {The {\TeX} book},
  date         = 1984,
  maintitle    = {Computers \& Typesetting},
  volume       = {A},
  publisher    = {Addison-Wesley},
  location     = {Reading, Mass.},
  langid       = {english},
  langidopts   = {variant=american},
  sortyear     = {1984-1},
  sorttitle    = {Computers & Typesetting A},
  indexsorttitle= {The TeXbook},
  indextitle   = {\protect\TeX book, The},
  shorttitle   = {\TeX book}
}
\end{filecontents*}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}

    test\footcite{knuth}   

    test\footnotemark[1] 
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you.. citation is in bottom of the slide. but if citation is given twice (to two points) in the slide, same citation appears twice in the bottom also with two different numbers.

Comment: @Alex Don't use `\footcite` two times, replace the second with `\footnotemark[whatever number]`

Comment: if same citation is used in different slide, it comes with different number in the bottom of slide. I want it to be same throughout just as citation in one document.